# bibtex for a book does not work in latex

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite this book as a bib text in latex:

[enter link description here](http://personal.disco.unimib.it/Vanneschi/McGrawHill_-_Machine_Learning_-Tom_Mitchell.pdf)

So I created the bibtex as follow:

```
@book{mschinLearning,
author    = {Tom M. Mitchell}, 
title     = {Machine learning},
publisher = {Mac Gew Hill},
 year      = 1997,
 volume    = 4,
 series    = 10,
address   = {The address},
 edition   = 3,
 month     = 7,
 note      = {An optional note},
 isbn      = {0071154671}
 }
```

But when I try it appears as [?] in the latex what's wrong with? can anyone help?

Update:blg file content:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: typeinst.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: myreferences.bib
Repeated entry---line 43 of file myreferences.bib
: @inproceedings{bamman2015contextualized
:                                        ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 228 of file myreferences.bib
: @inproceedings{davidov2010semi
:                               ,
 I' m skipping whatever remains of this entry
 Warning--empty journal in liebrecht2013perfect
  (There were 2 error messages)
```

Comment: Did you run `bibtex foo` after `pdflatex foo`? (Assuming your document is called `foo.tex`)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer when I copy the bibtext for other refrence from google evrything is perfect but since I could not find the bibtex for this book I made by myself and I think the problem that it does not work is because of that

Comment: @HamedMinaee does bibtex/latex raised any errors/warning?

Comment: Perhaps, but that wasn't my question. Either there is some error in your @book - entry or you've used another name in `\cite{}`, but not `mschinLearning`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no I cite it correctly I think sth is wrong in my @ book because latex show other biblatex refrences properly but I do not where my problem is

Comment: @RomainPicot No error or related warnings

Comment: Please post a complete, small document which we can compile to reproduce the error. Right now, it is just a guessing game: there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, the errors are unrelated to the code you've posted and neither errors nor code explain the problem you are reporting. Without information about what's causing the problem, it is just an unlucky dip.